# ¿A qué se debe este fallo en las colas de revisión de SOes?

Tags: soporte

estoy tratando de pasar por las colas de revisión pero está fallando al atender un elemento y pasar al siguiente en la cola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No cambia mi conteo de elementos atendidos en esa cola y no carga nada. Si vuelvo al inicio de SOes y vuelvo a ir a la cola de revisión, carga correctamente otro elemento pero vuelve a fallar al atenderlo.

Comment: Cual es la pregunta que falla?

Comment: Intenté tres veces ir a la cola de revisión, me salieron tres _cosas_ diferentes para revisar y las tres fallaron. No recuerdo ya cuáles fueron

Comment: no me estaria pasando... pero estemos atento, sobre todo si te pasa a vos solo

Comment: Pues volví a ver una de las que me salió entonces y esta vez la procesó bien. Supongo que ya le pasó el hipo a la cola de revisión. Si lo vuelvo a ver, les contaré